# Why does my form not submit and redirect?

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to migrate our site to a new host that uses PHP5. Previously we were on PHP4.

I have a form that is not submitting and redirecting to the thankyou page after a user fills out a survey which worked previously on php4. I'm sure it's probably something obvious that I'm missing but I can't see why it doesn't work.

When I click submit, the survey page reloads, the URL gets ?submit=t added to the end and the email is not sent to me.

The code from our survey.php is shown below with my email address and most of the HTML form feilds removed. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

```
  <?
$APP_ROOT = "../";
$FILE = __FILE__;
$TITLE="Service Survey";

if(!isset($submit)) {

    include($APP_ROOT."include/header.php");
    include($APP_ROOT."include/nava.php");
?>
<div class="bodymargin">
     <img src="<?=$WEB_ROOT;?>images/titles/<?=$SECTION."_".$FILE;?>.gif" width="400" height="36"><br>
    <br>
     <form method="POST" action="<?=$FILE;?>.php?submit=t">

<?
    if(isset($error)) {
        while(list($key, $value) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS)) {  
            $$key = stripslashes($value);
        }
        print("<p class=\"alert\">". urldecode($error) . "</p>\n"); 
    }
?> 
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$name;?>">
</form>

<?  
    include($APP_ROOT."include/navb.php");
    include($APP_ROOT."include/footer.php");
} else {
    include_once($APP_ROOT . "functions/index.php");
    include_once($APP_ROOT . "functions/form_validation.php");
    $CONTINUE = TRUE;


    $valid = new Validation($HTTP_POST_VARS);
    if($CONTINUE = $valid->success) {
        $to = "myemailaddress";
        $subject = "Service Survey";
        $from_email = $to;
        $from_name = "mysite.com";
        $headers = "From: $from_name<$from_email>\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: <$email>\n";
        $headers .= "Return-Path: <$from_email>\n"; 

        $body = "The following information was just posted \n";

        unset($HTTP_POST_VARS['required_fields']);
        reset($HTTP_POST_VARS);
        while(list($key, $value) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
            if(!empty($value)) {
                $body .= proper_form($key) . ":  " . stripslashes($value) ."\n";
            }   
        }
        $body .= "\nThis is an automated message, please do not respond.";
        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
        $URL = $WEB_ROOT . "/customer/thanks.php?form=" . $FILE;
        server_redirector($URL);
    } else {
        while(list($key, $value) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
            $rebound .= "&$key=" . urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        }
        $URL = $WEB_ROOT . "customer/survey.php?error=". urlencode(nl2br($valid->errors)) . $rebound;
        server_redirector($URL);
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: action="<?=$FILE;?>.php?submit=t">

Comment: i think Dieter has a good point.  should it be `<? echo $FILE; $>.php?sumit=t` ? is your server error log showing any errors?  this code is pretty ugly

Comment: also this script is using 'magic constants' which are only available if certain extensions are installed and enabled.  i would output those values to the screen just to make sure those values are set and not empty. more here ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regsiter_globals` is not active in newer PHP versions.
So instead of using `if(!isset($submit))` you have to use `if(!isset($_GET['submit']))`. And for posted values, you use `$_POST['parameter']`.

Comment: This was it. Once I replaced that and the the $_POST all was well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `__FILE__` constant is possibly not returning what you expect, or not what it previously did. from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> Since PHP 4.0.2, __ FILE__ always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

So you may be getting an absolute path now, instead of a relative one.

Also check if your new installation allows for `short_open_tags` as [explained in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: Good point, but I just checked and `__FILE__` is returning survey which I would expect. Also checked the short_open_tags and that is allowed too... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$HTTP_POST_VARS is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). You will want to replace it with $_POST.

Alternatively, you can just add $HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST; at the beginning of the script to avoid editing every line (Not really recommended).